# Server Error in '/' Application. (The resource cannot be found. )

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I have created an MVC project in Visual Studio 2017 , i have added few controllers for Web pages which are working fine ,
Now i want to create web APIs in the same project , so for that in **App_Start** folder i added a class for **WEB API config**

here is the code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Http;

namespace TestApp.App_Start
{
    public class WebApiConfig
    {
        public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
            // Web API routes
            config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );
        }     
    }
}
```

and in the controllers folder  where already controllers for web pages  were created
i added a Web Api Controller name `ValController`  with default read write actions

here it is

```
namespace TestApp
{
    public class ValController : ApiController
    {
        // GET api/<controller>
        public IEnumerable<string> Get()
        {
            return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
        }

        // GET api/<controller>/5
        public string Get(int id)
        {
            return "value";
        }                
    }
}
```

But when i run it 
i try to access this on this `url: localhost:44364/Val/Get` or
`localhost:44364/api/Val/Get`

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>   The resource cannot be found.

any kind of help will be appreciated

Comment: The code has given you an example of how to call it in the comment above the function definition. Remove the `get` from the end of your url e.g. `localhost:44364/api/Val/`. And use `localhost:44364/api/Val/5` to call the second one.

Comment: again its the same error

Comment: The controller name is ValController their for the url is localhost:44364/api/ValController. where is to specified the [Val] in the controller page.

Comment: @Bibin its the same error resource can'nt be found

Comment: What was the error?is occur to run this url : localhost:44364/api/ValController.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

every thing seems fine at your end

just one thing

check whether you have  added this in your `Global.asax.cs` file

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue is with the api controller file structure. Basically MVC works by "Convention over configuration", api added inside App_Data may not be identified by MVC router. Can you please create new folder named "Api", outside App_Data, just as immediate child of project and move the api code to that folder?

Also, as per the given routing config, you could check the below urls.

```
* localhost:<port>/api/Val
* localhost:<port>/api/Val/5
```

Also, as @David said, include the {action} part in route url

```
routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}"
```

Answer (score 0):

The routing you set up is controller/param you need to set it up controller/ACTION/param.

```
 routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
```